# How to set a specific future datetime timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

I would LIKe to know how to set a specific DateTime timestamp using the DateTime module in python. For example if I want ... To happen on 1 August 2022. How can I make a DateTime timestamp that will hold that date. Thanks for all help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a new `datetime` object with your date (and optionally with time) and then call timestamp() on it.
For example, you can do:

```py
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = datetime(2022, 8, 1).timestamp()
# timestamp is now 1659304800.0
```

You can find the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

Answer (score 1):

To create a date, we can use the `datetime()` class (constructor) of the `datetime` module.

The `datetime()` class requires three parameters to create a date: year, month, day.

**Example**

Create a date object:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17)

print(x)
```

[source](http://w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp)